# Build conda package with subpackages

Tags: python, bash, package, cython, conda-build

I am trying to build my conda package local souce using `conda build`.
The package has the following folder structure:

```
.
├── package1
│   ├── module.py
│   ├── secondmodule.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── build.sh
├── conda_build_config.yaml
├── environment.yml
├── meta.yaml
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── subpackages
    ├── subpackage1
        ├── subpackage1wrapper.py
        ├── subpackage1cython.pyx 
        ├── compile.sh
        ├── lib
        │   ├── Makefile
        │   ├── Cfunctions.cpp
        │   └── Cheaders.h
        ├── Makefile
        └── setup.py
```

As you can see the package has three key elements.

1. A main `package1`
2. A subpackage folder `subpackages` containing a subpackage `subpackage1` with some C functions, some Cython definitions and python `subpackage2`, each made of C files to be compiled.

`package1` has `subpackage1` has dependency.

My conda `build.sh` script contains:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Install package1
$PYTHON setup.py install     # Python command to install the script.

# Install subpackage1
cd subpackages/subpackage1

# compile the c code
cd lib
make

cd ..
make

# install the python package
$PYTHON setup.py install
```

Upon building, the subpackage is correctly compiled, Cythonized and installed.
However, upon testing, following the `test` section of my `meta.yaml`:

```yaml
...
test:
  imports:
    - package1
...
```

I get the error:

```bash
    import subpackage1 as subp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage1'
```

Can someone provide a MWE for `conda build`ing a similar package structure?